# ManytoManyField Django : how to call models in methods?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, model, manytomanyfield

I need help for something, I want to call models with ManyToManyField.
I want to have method to get Class A from Class B, and another in Class B to get Class A.

here's my (shortened) code :

```py
class Licence(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='finder/static/finder/img/licence/',null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    #returns a list of games from this license
    def getGamesOnThisLicence(self):

        #i don't know how to proceed

class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField()
    release_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    licence = models.ManyToManyField(Licence, blank=True, null=True)

    #return name of licence to which the game belongs
    def getLicenceName(self):
        return self.licence.name
```

Comment: Since this is a `ManyToManyField`, `self.license.name` makes no sense, since the collection can contain zero, one or more `License`s.

Comment: @MythMega Can you really have more than one license for one game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `Game`s with:

```
my_license.game_set.all()
```

so you can use `self` in the `getGamesOnThisLicense`, but probably there is not much gain to define a function since this makes accessing the `Game`s already quite convenient.

Perhaps you however want to transform the `ManyToManyField` into a `ForeignKey` to `License` since `self.license.name` makes not much sense: for a `ManyToManyField`, `self.license` is a `Manager` over `License` objects that can manage zero, one or more `License`s, so you can not use `self.license.name`.